# Using Enzyme to test React components that don't use classes or IDs

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme

I have the following in the `render` method of one of my components:'

```
  return <Paper key={insight._id} style={styles[viewMode]}>
    {cardCover}

    <div style={styles[viewMode].content}>
      <div
        style={styles[viewMode].name}
        onTouchTap={_ => onClickInsight(insight._id)}
      >
        {insight.title}
      </div>
      [...]
```

It seems that since Enzyme works around using selectors, my best option is to just use put `className="something"` on my divs, even if I'm not using them as CSS classes at all. Otherwise, I have to figure out how many divs are within Material UI's `Paper` component, and work out some overly complicated query to dig X levels deep into divs, just to get to my clickable div that I want to test. Not to mention, if I happen to move my clickable div down or up a bit, it breaks the test even though the div is technically still being rendered and still clickable.

Unless there's another way?

Answer (score 0):

Enzyme gives you a few options here on top of CSS selectors. You could `find()` using a [React Component Constructor](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/selector.md#2-a-react-component-constructor) to first find your Paper component, and then use a CSS selector from there.

`const myComponent = wrapper.find(Paper);`

If you just want to verify that some child has `onTouchTap` set, you can use the [prop syntax](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/selector.md#1-a-valid-css-selector) css selector.